# Is there a way to filter data on one sheet based on lookup table from another sheet?

Tags: excel, lookup, excel-2016, worksheet-function, worksheet

I'm trying to utilize a cell as a drop down to filter rows on one sheet based on a lookup that exists on another sheet. Please see below for an example of what I mean:

Assume that table on left is Sheet 1 and right is Sheet 2. You can see that on Sheet 1, I can filter employees by their name. I am hoping to use cell A1 as another filter, but by department name. For that I have a lookup table on Sheet 2 that assigns each employee by their respective department.

Is there a way to filter Sheet 1 using the lookup table in Sheet 2? I looked into the FILTER function but it seems like it does not accomplish what I'm hoping it to.

[image]

Comment: the easiest way is to add a column to the first table that has an INDEX/MATCH that returns the department, Then you can filter on that column in the first table.

Comment: You may also be able to accomplish this with a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

In *Sheet1*, cell *C3* create this formula:
`=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!B:B,0))`
Copy the formula down.
You should get the result like below. Recreate the auto filter and you will be able to use it as you want.

[image]

Comment: @sudden_clarity_clarence - what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @sudden_clarity_clarence,

I'll give you a solution following some Best Practices.
I expect you appreciate my answer.
Please rate this session accordingly and leave me any comments you have!

So let's create a clear viewable example.
For this case I recommend you to:

- Use this clear formula:

  `=VLOOKUP([@Employee],Sheet2_tabDEPARTMENT,2,TRUE)`
- Always name cell intervals, sheets, Table Objects, with easily unmistakable identifiable name.
- In this case I renamed Sheet2 to "Sheet2_tabDEPARTMENT" where the correspondent Employee's Department is
- When possible I usually insert a Table Object in my data tables (ribbon:Insert\Table). In this way you get automatic human readable column naming.
- For clarity I usually rename the Table Object data cell range to the same sheet name. In this case renamed Sheet2's Table object to "Sheet2_tabDEPARTMENT", same name as the sheet.
- When possible use VLOOKUP() function instead INDEX MATCH combination.
- VLOOKUP() it's clear to understand and is adequate for 99% of these kind of requirement.
- VLOOKUP() looks to match the value in [Employee] column to the first column
- Don't forget that the key column to lookup must be the first, leftmost, on the lookup list table.
- Don't forget to add to VLOOKUP() the 4th argument "FALSE", to ensure you get the exact match or "N/A" not available is employee is not on the list.

[IMAGE:Sheet1 Main Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSDH5.png)

[IMAGE:Sheet2 Data lookup Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkO7C.png)

[IMAGE:VLOOKUP Function Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL45A.png)